# Retrieving prediction result in negative

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, random-forest, xgboost

I have the following sample data using regression algorithm to predict time.
I trained the model using lightgbm and xgboost too, however, I am retrieving very bad prediction result and prediction results are negative. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

```
size channels time
3    3      4.980278
3    16     4.972054
3    64     4.899884
3    256    5.499221
3    512    5.599495
3    1024   5.936933
16   3      5.221653
16   16     5.994821
16   64     6.648254
16   256    7.176828
16   512    8.1707
16   1024   8.651496
64   3      7.801533
64   16     7.398248
64   64     8.395648
64   256    17.49494
64   512    26.43354
64   1024   49.55192
256  3      12.36093
256  16     20.50781
256  64     46.49553
256  256    170.5452
256  512    333.8809
256  1024   675.9459
512  3      22.44313
512  16     53.82643
512  64     164.3493
512  256    659.4345
512  512    1306.881
512  1024   3122.403
```

lightbgm code

```
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X,Y, train_size=0.8)
print(f"Number of training examples {len(x_train)}")
print(f"Number fo testing examples {len(x_val)}")
regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
train_pred = regressor.predict(x_train)
train_rmse = mean_squared_error(train_pred, y_train) ** 0.5
print(f"Train RMSE is {train_rmse}")
val_pred = regressor.predict(x_val)
val_rmse = mean_squared_error(val_pred, y_val)**0.5 
print(f"Test RMSE is {val_rmse}")
R_squared = r2_score(val_pred,y_val)
print('R2',R_squared)
```

Result

```
Train RMSE is 5385.50, Test RMSE is 1245.1,R2 -2.9991290197894976e+31
```

XGBoost code optimised using optuna

```
def optimize(trial,x,y,regressor):
  max_depth = trial.suggest_int("max_depth",3,10)
  n_estimators = trial.suggest_int("n_estimators",5000,10000)
  max_leaves= trial.suggest_int("max_leaves",1,10)
  learning_rate = trial.suggest_loguniform('learning_rate', 0.001, 0.1)
  colsample_bytree = trial.suggest_uniform('colsample_bytree', 0.0, 1.0) 
  min_child_weight = trial.suggest_uniform('min_child_weight',1,3)
  subsample = trial.suggest_uniform('subsample', 0.5, 1)

  model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    objective ='reg:squarederror',
    n_estimators=n_estimators,
    max_depth=max_depth,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree,
    min_child_weight=min_child_weight,
    max_leaves=max_leaves,
    subsample = subsample
)
  kf=model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5)
  error=[]
  for idx in kf.split(X=x , y=y):
    train_idx , test_idx= idx[0],idx[1]
    xtrain=x[train_idx]
    ytrain=y[train_idx]
    xtest=x[test_idx]
    ytest=y[test_idx]   
    model.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
    y_pred = model.predict(xtest)
    fold_err = metrics.mean_squared_error(ytest,y_pred)
    error.append(np.sqrt(fold_err))
  return np.mean(error)
  best_params={{'max_depth': 9, 'n_estimators': 9242, 'max_leaves': 7, 'learning_rate': 0.0015809052065858954, 'colsample_bytree': 0.4908644884609704, 'min_child_weight': 2.3502876962874435, 'subsample': 0.5927926099148189}
def optimize_xgb(X,y):
  list_of_y = ["Target 1"]
  for i,m in zip(range(y.shape[1]),list_of_y):
    print("{} optimized Parameters on MSE Error".format(m))
    optimization_function = partial(optimize , x=X,y=y[:,i],regressor="random_forest")
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")
    study.optimize(optimization_function,n_trials=50)
optimize_xgb(X_train, y_train)
def modeling(X,
             y,
             optimize = "no",
             max_depth=50,
             n_estimators=3000,
             max_leaves=30,
             learning_rate=0.01,
             colsample_bytree=1.0,
             gamma=0.0001,
             min_child_weight=2,
             reg_lambda=0.0001):
  if optimize == "no":
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror')
  else:
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror',
                          **best_params)
  if y.shape[1] ==1:
    model_xgb = model.fit(X, y)

  cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
  scores = []
  for i in range(y.shape[1]):
    scores.append(np.abs(cross_val_score(model, X, y[:,i], scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)))
    print('Mean MSE of the {} target : {}  ({})'.format(i,scores[i].mean(), scores[i].std()) )
  return model_xgb
model_xgb = modeling(X_train,y_train, optimize="yes")
model_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model_xgb.predict(X_test)
MSE = mse(y_pred,y_test)
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE)
print("TEST MSE",MSE)
R_squared = r2_score(y_pred,y_test)
print("RMSE: ", np.round(RMSE, 2))
print("R-Squared: ", np.round(R_squared, 2))
```

The result for xgboost

```
TEST MSE 2653915.139388934,RMSE:  1629.08,R-Squared:  -1.69
```

Comment: Y→log(Y) and then training the XGBoost to predict  logY

Comment: @BlackMath, Thanks alot for your response. I would appreciate if you would elaborate more on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to say that Gradient Boosting models can return values inside and outside of the training range.

GB Regressors fit trees using residuals of the previous stage. So,
if a predicted value at stage `t` is larger than the target variable, the residual of stage `t` is going to be negative,then the regression tree at stage `t+1` will deal with that negative target values from previous residuals.

Adding these obtained trees, stage by stage, model can predict negative values.

A common technique for handling negative values in prediction models is the logarithmic trasformation.

The transformation of the target variable is `Y -> log(Y+c)` where `c` is the constant. People usually  choose something like `Y -> log(Y+0.001)` or any other "very small" positive number.